# I need to sort MYSQL results by a number passed in OR another column

Tags: mysql, sorting, multiple-columns

Here is my table with my select statement:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2caf/1)
I want to group by `job_id` and then sort it by a number passed in, (in this case the number is 2)
If there is no match then show result with default marked as true
If none are marked as true then sort by `production_days` DESC

The end result should have:

[image]

All jobs show column with `production_days` = 2 except 103 which did not have a matching column, this was sorted by `is_default` DESC

I have tried

```
SELECT *, CASE production_days 
WHEN 2 THEN 0 
WHEN is_default = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 2 
END as sort
FROM `jobs` GROUP BY JOB_ID ORDER BY JOB_ID, sort
```

**EDIT:**
The desired results are: rows with unique `job_id` that have the number **2** in the `production_days` column if that `job_id` does not have a 2 in the column then I am looking for a **1** in the `is_default` column. I do not care how the results are achieved but I would like to do it in one select statement.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know what (you think) you mean by 'group by'

Comment: The MySQL GROUP BY clause is used with the SELECT statement to group rows into subgroups by the one or more values of columns or expressions. Basically I want the results to show unique job_id's sorted by the criteria I stated in my question.

Comment: The expected results are in the image above. Right after the statement
"The end result should have:"

Comment: What is the deciding factor between job_id 100 using id 2 and not id 1?

Comment: You're misusing the pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. It's going to be very hard indeed to get this query working predictably because of that.  Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @McAdam331 - I am passing in a number, in this case it is 2. I am trying to match the `production_days` column with that number.  If there is no match it will match by the `is_default` column DESC (looking for a value of 1)

Comment: @OllieJones - I am just trying to proper results, if the `group by` will not work correctly I am not opposed to getting the results a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to rephrase this as I understand it: you want to sort jobs that have production_days = 2 first, then jobs where is_default is true, and then the other jobs.

To do that, I first broke the query down into three groups and put them together. I started by getting the ones that had the value 2 in production_days, which was the easiest. I hardcoded a 0 at the end to demonstrate this is the first group:

```
SELECT j.*, 0
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.production_days = 2;
```

Then, I found the jobs that had is_default = 1 that did not have a production_days of 2, like this:

```
SELECT j.*, 1
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.is_default = 1 
AND j.job_id NOT IN (
  SELECT job_id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE production_days = 2);
```

For the last group, you just need to check for jobs that aren't in either of the previous lists. This actually simplifies it a bit because you can narrow down the requirement to projects that have production_days of 2, or have is_default = 1:

```
SELECT j.*, 2
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.job_id NOT IN(
  SELECT job_id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE is_default = 1
  OR production_days = 2);
```

The last step is to combine and sort the results. You could use a UNION, and then order by sortPosition like this:

```
SELECT j.*, 0 AS sortPosition
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.production_days = 2
UNION
SELECT j.*, 1 AS sortPosition
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.is_default = 1 
AND j.job_id NOT IN (
  SELECT job_id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE production_days = 2)
UNION
SELECT j.*, 2 AS sortPosition
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.job_id NOT IN(
  SELECT job_id
  FROM jobs
  WHERE is_default = 1
  OR production_days = 2)
ORDER BY job_id, sortPosition;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2caf/27) example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an 'old school' solution... (although it makes certain assumptions about your dataset that might not be true)

```
SELECT j.*
  FROM jobs j
 JOIN 
    ( SELECT id,job_id, 1 rank FROM jobs WHERE production_days = 2
        UNION
       SELECT id,job_id, 2  FROM jobs WHERE is_default = 1
     ) a
    ON a.id = j.id
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,job_id, 1 rank FROM jobs WHERE production_days = 2
        UNION
       SELECT id,job_id, 2  FROM jobs WHERE is_default = 1
     ) b
    ON b.job_id = a.job_id
   AND b.rank < a.rank
 WHERE b.id IS NULL
```